# "Find $k$ such that $P(0,2)$ is equidistant from $(3,k)$ and $(k,5)$." Why can't we use the Midpoint Formula?

Tags: geometry

> Find the value of $k$ if the point $P(0 ,2)$ is equidistant from $(3, k)$ and $(k, 5)$.

In this question, usually we take points in the form of a triangle and solve by distance formula. Why can't we take points in straight line and take $P$ as midpoint and solve by Midpoint Formula?

If we can, then please provide solutions for both cases.

Comment: because three points may not be on the same line

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

You can't do that because $p$ need not be on the straight line connecting $(3,k)$ and $(k,5)$.

Instead solve for $$(3-0)^2+(k-2)^2 =(k-0)^2 + (5-2)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's calculate the distance from $P$ to $(3, k)$ and $(k, 5)$.
By definition, the distances are
$$
d((0, 2), (3, k))=\sqrt{(0-3)^2+(k-2)^2}=\sqrt{9+(k-2)^2}
$$
and
$$
d((0, 2), (k, 5))=\sqrt{(0-k)^2+(2-5)^2}=\sqrt{(-k)^2+9}=\sqrt{k^2+9}
$$
These distances are equal, therefore
$$
\sqrt{9+(k-2)^2}=\sqrt{k^2+9}
$$
Squaring, we get that
$$
9+(k-2)^2=k^2+9
$$
or
$$
(k-2)^2=k^2
$$
This is equivalent to $k^2-4k+4=k^2$ or $-4k+4=0$. Subtracting $4$ from both sides we get $-4k=-4$ or $\boxed{k=1}$